# I wan't to format a string of numbers as a currency in javascript but i don't know how to format my string

Tags: javascript, typescript

so what i mean is:

1000 should become 10,00 
10000 should become 100,00 
100000 should become 1000,00

Can some help me out?

Comment: I think you want Intl.NumberFormat https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: What have you tried? It's just removing two last 00 and merging with `,` (basic string manipulation). E.g. `('' + number).replace(/(\d)(\d{2})$/, '$1,$2')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers as currency strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings)

Comment: Are you working in Node.js? Client-side JS? For what country/locale/currency are you trying to format the value? Also it sounds like you are dealing with integer values in hundredths of a unit so as to avoid the problems of floating point, so $123.00 would be represented as the integer 12300, right? From a formatting point-of-view, that's a simple matter scaling the number appropriately.

Comment: @Justinas, thanks you solved for me, i don't know how to make you're awnser the solution though

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#using_options

```
var number = 1000;

// request a currency format
console.log(number.toLocaleString('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }));
```

Without methods and just formatting with commas

```
        function addComma(value) {
            return value.split('').map((v, i) => {
                if ( i === value.length - 2) {
                    return ',' + v
                }
                return v
            }).join('')
        }
        console.log(addComma('1000'))
        console.log(addComma('10000'))
        console.log(addComma('100000'))
```

Comment: Thanks but not what i'am looking this adds two zero's behind the comma but i need my last two zero's behind the comma so 1000 whould become 10,00 instead of 1000,00

Comment: ill update, just a moment

Comment: What happens if something costs only 5 cents, i.e. if `value == '5'`?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.delftstack.com/howto/javascript/javascript-currency-format/

you can transform your string in number and then use toLocaleString()

here is an example from the webpage

```
const number = 2000;
number.toLocaleString('en-IN', {style: 'currency',currency: 'INR', minimumFractionDigits: 2})
console.log(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, just splitting the string into *whole* and *cents*:

```js
function addComma(n)
{
    if (n.length == 0) {
       return '0,00';
    }

    if (n.length == 1) {
       return '0,0' + n;
    }

    if (n.length == 2) {
       return '0,' + n;
    }

    let whole = n.substring(0, n.length-2);
    let cents = n.substring(n.length-2);
    return whole + ',' + cents;
}
```